# Run Image Docker Dotnet Core 6.0 In Windows

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api application, I need to run it in a docker container.
This is my dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
    
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore "WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
    
    
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "../WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
    
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "../WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
    
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

This is my *Program.cs* config:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
// Add services to the container.
    
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
var app = builder.Build();
    
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
    
app.UseAuthorization();
    
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
    
app.Run();
```

Those are logs of an app:

```bash
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
          Now listening on: http://localhost:80
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. 
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Hosting environment: Production
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Content root path: C:\app\
```

But the application is not working when I try to open it in chrome, it gives me 'This site can’t be reached'

Command To Build Image:

`docker build --pull -t web-app .`

Command To Run Image:

`docker run -d -p 5000:80 -it web-app`

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the command used to start the container.

Comment: @Turing85 i do this thank you

Comment: In the `Dockerfile`, you wrote `EXPOSE 80`, suggesting that the application is running on port 80, but in the `docker run...` command, you export `-p 5000:5000`. On what port is the application *actually* listening?

Comment: @Turing85 first i try with 80 and not working and after i try with 5000

Comment: When you start the application locally (i.e. not in docker), what port is it listening to?

Comment: @Turing85 56916

Comment: That looks suspiciously high... anyway. If this is the port (and it's always the same, i.e. not random), then this is the port we should `EXPOSE` in the `Dockerfile` and forward with `docker run -p ...`. On the other hand, the application reports listening on `http://localhost:5000`.... you try to access the app through `http://localhost:5000`?

Comment: @Turing85 Not working !

Comment: @Turing85 `EXPOSE` is merely documentation, it only declares that you are listening on that port, but it doesn't actually have any impact in the app itself.

Comment: @jccampanero I know.

Comment: Sorry @Turing85, I brought it up just to clarify the point to the OP to avoid confusion due to your previous comment.

Comment: @jccampanero np :)

Comment: what are you trying to access from chrome, swagger page or direct api call ? in case you trying swagger then it won't be accessible due to condition `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()`